# What is functionality of the '[recur]' in 'return (None, [lng])[recur]'

Tags: python, recursion, return-value, square-bracket

I've solved this [challange](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55466989aeecab5aac00003e) on CodeWars in the other way, and now I'm learning from other solutions. [One of them](https://www.codewars.com/kata/reviews/554669fabd94d086550001fd/groups/5553209f151776bc44000031) is:

```
# Recursive solution
def sqInRect(lng, wdth, recur = 0):
    if lng == wdth:
        return (None, [lng])[recur]            # If this is original function call, return None for equal sides (per kata requirement);
                                               # if this is recursion call, we reached the smallest square, so get out of recursion.
    lesser = min(lng, wdth)
    return [lesser] + sqInRect(lesser, abs(lng - wdth), recur = 1)
```

Could you please explain me what does this line mean: `return (None, [lng])[recur]` (the `[recur]` especially - I didn't see such a thing anywhere... is it an index, list or something? What functionality does it provide?). I know what does the code do, because mine does the same thing in another way, but I'm asking just about this sqare bracket in `return`
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, it's an index. `return (None, [lng])[recur]` is more or less equivalent to `if recur==0: return None; elif recur==1: return [lng]; else: raise IndexError`

Comment: It looks like it's used as an index into the tuple created `(None, lng)`, so if you're in a recursive call (recur=1) it'll return lng, else it'll return `None`.

Comment: *"and now I'm learning from other solutions."* Please don't learn this. Using weird tuple indexing like this to avoid a conditional just makes everything harder to maintain. It's really not a good coding practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing magic about it; it's tuple indexing, plain and simple.

`(None, [lng])` creates a tuple with two elements, and `[recur]` grabs the first or second element of this tuple depending on whether `recur` is 0 or 1.

Comment: It's slightly less simple that that. For instance, `recur` could be a boolean.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I undersand python can do such a magic ;) Very smart solution to this problem ;)

Comment: @WoogieBoogie No, it's not smart. It's a trick that obfuscates the code for no reason. It's used a lot on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com for obvious reasons, but if you see it anywhere else, it's not clever, it's a bad trick.